# Accessing a property of the last object in an array in computed vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an empty products array and users can add new products if they want. My goal is I want to save the last `productKey` and save it in a Vuex state.

```
//data
products: []

//method
addNewProduct() {
      this.products.push({
        productKey: '',
        productName: ''
      })
},
```

I want to get the key of the last added product (last object). I've tried this way

```
lastKey() {
  return this.products[this.products.length-1].productKey
}
```

This doesn't work as it says `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productKey')`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: What do you want `lastKey` to return if the `products` array is empty?

Answer (score 5):

All state-related (including `computed` properties) run before hook `created` .Because **products** is initially empty so you try to access `productKey` of last item will result `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productKey')`. You can use **optional chaining** to check possibility exists.

```js
lastKey() {
  return this.products[this.products.length-1]?.productKey
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As products is an `empty` array inside data object and you are assigning the data in it later on by using `mounted()` or `methods`.

Initially, `computed` property always execute before `mounted` life cycle hook to create the property and at that time products is an empty array. Hence, It is giving `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productKey')` error.

To get rid from this error, You can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Live demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    products: []
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted call'); // This calls 
    this.products.push({
      productKey: 'key1',
      productName: 'name1'
    })
  },
  computed: {
    lastKey: function() {
      console.log('computed call'); // This calls before mounted life cycle hook to create the lastKey property and it will call again after mounted() as there is a change in the products array.
      return this.products[this.products.length - 1]?.productKey;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ lastKey }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your code is already correct. this happened because products array is empty